# Use of undefined constant layouts - assumed 'layouts' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

Hello I am trying to make a new view named `showrecord` but it shows error:

> Use of undefined constant layouts - assumed 'layouts' (this will throw
>   an Error in a future version of PHP)

**View structure:**

[image]

**Controller:**

```php
public function index()
{
    return view('showrecord');
}
```

**Route:**

```php
Route::resource('showrecord','ShowrecordController');
```

how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since i can't be able to look into your code

So You are extending your view

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

So my Assumption is You are missing

Single Quotes

```
@extends(layouts.app)
```

I Will give You error

Try Adding Single Or Double Quotes

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that you copy/paste code with the wrong single quote:

> @include(‘layouts.includes.header’) <= here the apostrophe is used instead of quote

to be replaced by

> @include('layouts.includes.header')

Answer (score 0):

if you face such a problem, one of the reason is that when you declare a variable in frontend(view) you forget to declare the variable in its the proper  syntax for example we
you declare like this {{$user-description}} then by mistake you declare the wrong syntax because the right syntax is {{$user->description}} [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akeGl.png)